# Using FileDialog to attach a file to an email

Tags: excel, vba, email

I want to eliminate human error when it comes to selecting a file to send in an attachment in an email.  Basically eliminating this code `Filename = Application.InputBox("Enter File Name:", "", "File Name")'Type in File Name`  And replace it using `FileDialog` which has come to my attention as a good way of accomplishing this.  I am very confused on how to use it correctly.  Every time I have tried, I am able to use the application and see the file but I don't understand how it gets attached.  My email coding is below.

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Test()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Date1 As Date
    Dim Recipient As Variant


Date1 = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
'Date and format
UserName = Application.InputBox("Enter your name:", "", "FirstLast")
Filename = Application.InputBox("Enter File Name:", "", "File Name")
'Type in File Name

List = Application.InputBox("Enter Email List Name:", "", "ListName")
'Type in Email List
If List = "gold" Then
List = "example@mail.com; example1@mail.com; example2@mail.com"
ElseIf List = "silver" Then
List = "example@mail.com; example@mail.com"
Else
MsgBox ("Sorry, your list selection was not recognised.")
Exit Sub
End If


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


With OutMail
For Each Recipient In Split(List, ";")
    .Recipients.Add Trim(Recipient)
Next
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "" + Filename + "" & " " & Date1
    .Body = "Hi Everyone," & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Please let me know if you get this!" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Thanks!"""
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\" + UserName + "\Desktop\" + Filename + ".xlsx")
    .Send   '.Display
End With


Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

How do I get `Filename =` to equal the file I pick with the code below and properly attach into an email?  Any advice on my coding would be great too, thank you!

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd


        .AllowMultiSelect = False
End with
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excerpt  from a similar subroutine of mine, hope you'll find it helpful. Place this somewhere between creating MailItem object and sending the message:

```vb
'Ask which files to open (using FileDialog)
Dim fdInputFile As FileDialog
Set fdInputFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With fdInputFile
    .Filters.Clear
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    If .Show = False Then Exit Function 'you might want to handle "Cancel" button differently
End With

'Attach all files
Dim sInputFile As Variant
For Each sInputFile In fdInputFile.SelectedItems
    OutMail.Attachments.Add sInputFile, 1
Next sInputFile
```

PS: I think it's easier to reuse the code above when it's separated from user input, so I use a separate function for creating e-mails whereever I need to. Just feed all the input as the parameters and call .Send method when you're ready

```vb
Public Function CreateEmailMsg(cRecipients, _
                        Optional sSubject As String = "", _
                        Optional sBody As String = "", _
                        Optional cAttachments = Nothing) _
                        As Object
'
' Generate new e-mail message
'
' Parameters:
'   cRecipients: String (or a Collection of Strings) containing
'                e-mail addresses of recipients
'   sSubject: String containing message subject line
'   sBody: String containing message body (HTML or plain text)
'   cAttachments: String (or a Collection of Strings) containing
'                 path(s) to attachments
'
' Returns MailItem object referring to the created message
' Most common methods for MailItem object are .Display and .Send
'
    Dim appOL As Object
    Set appOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim msgNew As Object
    Set msgNew = appOL.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

    Dim sItem
    With msgNew
        'Message body
        .BodyFormat = 2 'olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = sBody

        'Recipients
        If TypeName(cRecipients) = "String" Then
            .Recipients.Add cRecipients
        ElseIf Not cRecipients Is Nothing Then
            For Each sItem In cRecipients
                .Recipients.Add sItem
            Next sItem
        End If

        'Subject
        .Subject = sSubject

        'Attachments
        If TypeName(cAttachments) = "String" Then
            .Attachments.Add cAttachments, 1
        ElseIf Not cAttachments Is Nothing Then
            For Each sItem In cAttachments
                .Attachments.Add sItem, 1
            Next sItem
        End If
     End With

    Set CreateEmailMsg = msgNew
End Function
```

Comment: This helped a lot! THank you SIO!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Filename = Application.InputBox("Enter File Name:", "", "File Name")
```

with:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
Filename = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you!  Please accept answer so other helpers do not waste time checking the question, thanks

Comment: But if I wanted to select multiple files would you just change it to `.AllowMultiSelect = True` ?

Comment: Yes, also you will need to loop through the files you have selected (SelectedItems(itemcount)), and assign each of them accordingly